# Handling back to back AJAX calls without callbacks (if possible)

Tags: javascript, ajax, concurrency

I have a function in a web application that makes an AJAX call to update an element. I have other functions which use this function, and other functions which use those functions.

Say I have function A which makes an AJAX call. Function B calls function A, and function C calls function B.

Now imagine I have function D, which is another function that makes an AJAX call.

I want to call function C, then function D. The problem is I run into an issue where sometimes function D is using the response that was returned from the function C call. So I don't want function D to run until a response is received from function C's AJAX request.

Since the AJAX request happens so far down the chain (C > B > A), it seems like such a hack to have function C accept a callback, then pass that call back to B, which passes that callback to A so that A can call that callback function after it receives the response to it's AJAX request.

Is this actually the best way to do it, or can it be done more cleanly? If it makes a difference, I'd prefer a solution that doesn't use any extra libraries (like jQuery for example.)

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Just to clarify, why can't you use the Function A for making the ajax call instead of writing another function B which calls A and another fuction C which calls B? You just call Function A where ever its necessary.Am I correct?

Comment: In my particular example, function A is a generic AJAX request performing function, function B is a "Save File" function, and function C is a "Save File As" function. So "Save File As" does some stuff and inevitable calls "Save File", which also does some stuff and then calls function A to generate the AJAX request.

Comment: It's called promises, and it's hard to get it right without a library (and even with a library...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [promise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx) pattern.

Comment: Cheers, I knew there had to be something out there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you may bind ajax events to elements, instead of callbacks, use a library like http://phery-php-ajax.net if you are using PHP